# Why it says push is not a function when called?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function rotLeft(a, d) {
    var temp=[];
    temp=a.splice(0);
    for(let i=0; i<d-1; i++)
    {
        var first=temp.shift();
        temp=temp.push(first);
    }
    var result=temp;
    return temp;
}
```

if you know the rotate left problem in hackerrank, why woudnt this code work. The console says push is not a function. whats wrong in this code. Also please explain `arr.shift(arr.push(arr[0]));` this line. The first element is pushed to the last element and the first element is removed?

Comment: No need to assign. Try `temp.push(first);` instead of `temp=temp.push(first);`

Comment: [].push is a mutable operation, so returning itself could lead to misinterpretations on its behavior (if it were, say, concat, the new array gets returned instead).

Comment: the `.push` method adds an element at the end of an array and returns the new length of the array. After the first `temp=temp.push(first);` temp will no longer be an array, but a number

Answer (score 0):

It should be `temp.push(first);`  not `temp=temp.push(first);`

```js
function rotLeft(a, d) {
    var temp=[];
    temp=a.splice(0);
    for(let i=0; i<d-1; i++)
    {
        var first=temp.shift();
        temp.push(first);
    }
    var result=temp;
    return temp;
}
console.log(rotLeft([1,2,3,4,5,6],8))
```